# Can't do that: NodeJS server creates number, sends it to client via JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, server

My problem:

The server generates a random number and sends it to a client via JSON. When I open the client on different windows, it shows the same number. if I click on a refresh button, the number changes instantly on both clients.

I am new to Javascript, Node.js, and so on, because its my first month as a Software Engineer student in Germany and I'm only used to Java (not Javascript) and HTML.

```
   //my server:
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function (err, content) {
        if (err) {
            res.end('error occurred');
            return;
        }

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(content);
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(8124);

var ranNum = '{"number": "' + parseInt(Math.random() * 100000000) + '"}';

console.log("server at http://localhost:8124/");
```

Comment: The two clients (if, like I understood, they are web browsers) are not connected so one will have no idea when the other one has refreshed. If you want to do something like this, you'll have to use sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some explanation (*read comments in code*)

```js
//my server:
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');



// You create an http server <------------------------------------ this process finish here
http.createServer(function (req, res) {//                             instantly   
  // everything here happen after the end of your process                |
  // of http.createServer                                                |
  //                                                                     |   
  //                                                                     |   
  // here we have launched our server and are                            |
  // waiting for any connection.                                         |
  //                                                                     |   
  //                                                                     |
  // each a connection reach the server                                  |
  // we open a file called 'index.html'                                  |
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function (err, content) {//       |
        if (err) {// if an error occur on reading                        |
            //  we send a response to the client                         |
            //  to inform the webbrowser about the error                 |
            res.end('error occurred');//                                 |
            return;//                                                    |
        }//                                                              |
        // if no error we write a response to the client                 |
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});//             |
      // we tell 200 everything ok                                       |
      // in the format of : 'Content-Type': 'text/html'                  |
        res.write(content);// we insert in the response the content      |
      // the content of the file we have read, just now                  |
      //                                                                 |
        res.end();// we send the response to the client                  |
    });//                                                                |
}).listen(8124); // you tell the server to listen on port 8124 <----------
//          ^
//          |
//          |-------------------|
//                              °
// you have to call this port (8124) from 
// your webbrowser to reach the http server you just created.


// here you create a variable called ranNum
// you created this one time only
var ranNum = '{"number": "' + parseInt(Math.random() * 100000000) + '"}';

// ranNum should now be something like
// ranNum = '{"number": "37567307"}';


console.log("server at http://localhost:8124/");

// add this line to test :
console.log("ranNum : " , ranNum);

//your console will log the same thing one time only.
```

so in reality to send different number for each client you have to do something like that :

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    console.log("we have a request : " + new Date());

    var ranNum = '{"number": "' + parseInt(Math.random() * 100000000) + '"}';
    console.log("ranNum sent : " , ranNum);

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end(ranNum);

});

server.listen(8124);

console.log("server at http://localhost:8124/");
```

Comment: Me too ! It was a real pleasure to make them !